# Can't see my custom theme in my child component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have my entry component called app:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff4400',    
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#0044ff',
    },
  },
});

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
       <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <Main>
        <CssBaseline />
         ...loading
      </Main>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In here I create a theme and use the MuiThemeProvider to send it down to my children components.

The Main component looks like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  titleText: {
    color: theme.palette.primary,
  }
});



function Main(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography align="center" variant="title" className={classes.titleText}> Some Text </Typography> 
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Main.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


export default withStyles(styles, {withTheme:true})(Main);
```

I am expecting the text 'Some Text' will be in the color of #ff4400 but it is not, it is the default color that comes with materialui. Why is the primary color from the theme not coloring the text in the child component?

Comment: color: theme.palette.primary, should be color: theme.palette.primary.main Isn’t it?

Comment: Wow. I am the dumbest human being on this planet. Spent my whole Sunday on this. That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: NP. It happens, we all do silly mistakes :) I have added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
   color: theme.palette.primary,
```

To

```
   color: theme.palette.primary.main
```

In your Main component